# Issue with adding user ID to GraphQL recipe model and retrieving user-specific recipes

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, graphql

I'm having trouble adding the user ID to the createdBy field in my GraphQL recipe model. The code seems correct, but it's not working as expected. Additionally, I want to retrieve all the recipes related to the logged-in user only. I'm seeking assistance in identifying and resolving the issue.

Here is the relevant code snippets from my application:
Recipe Model:

```
const recipeSchema = new Schema({
  name: String,
  description: String,
  createdAt: String,
  thumbsUp: Number,
  thumbsDown: Number,
  createdBy: {
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'User',
  },
});

module.exports = model('Recipe', recipeSchema);
```

Resolvers:

```
module.exports = {
  Query: {
    async recipe(_, { ID }) {
      return await Recipe.findById(ID);
    },
    async getRecipes(_, { amount }) {
      return await Recipe.find().sort({ createdAt: -1 }).limit(amount);
    },
    async getUserRecipes(_, __, context) {
      auth(context);
      return await Recipe.find({ createdBy: context.userId }).sort({ createdAt: -1 });
    },
    
  },
  Mutation: {
    async createRecipe(_, { recipeInput: { name, description } }, context) {
      auth(context);
      const createdRecipe = new Recipe({
        name: name,
        description: description,
        createdAt: new Date().toISOString(),
        thumbsUp: 0,
        thumbsDown: 0,
        createdBy: context.userId,
      });
      const res = await createdRecipe.save();
      return {
        id: res.id,
        ...res._doc,
        createdBy: context.userId,
      };
    },
    
    async deleteRecipe(_, { ID }, context) {
      // Verify the user's authentication
      auth(context);
      const wasDeleted = (await Recipe.deleteOne({ _id: ID })).deletedCount;
      // 1 if something is deleted, 0 if nothing is deleted
      return wasDeleted;
    },
    async editRecipe(_, { ID, recipeInput: { name, description } }, context) {
      // Verify the user's authentication
       auth(context);
      const wasEdited = (await Recipe.updateOne(
        { _id: ID },
        { name: name, description: description }
      )).modifiedCount;
      // 1 if something is modified, 0 if nothing is modified
      return wasEdited;
    },
    async register(_, { registerInput: { username, email, password, confirmPassword } }) {
      // TODO: Validate input data (e.g., password length, email format, etc.)

      // Check if a user with the same username or email already exists
      const existingUser = await User.findOne({ $or: [{ username }, { email }] });
      if (existingUser) {
        throw new Error('Username or email is already taken.');
      }

      // Create a new user instance
      const newUser = new User({
        username,
        email,
        password,
        createdAt: new Date().toISOString(),
        updatedAt: new Date().toISOString(),
      });

      // Save the new user to the database
      const res = await newUser.save();

      // Generate and return a token for the registered user
      const token = generateToken(res);

      // Return the user data without the password
      return {
        id: res.id,
        ...res._doc,
        password: null,
        token,
      };
    },
    async login(_, { loginInput: { username, password } }) {
      // Check if a user with the provided username exists
      const user = await User.findOne({ username });
      if (!user) {
        throw new Error('User not found.');
      }

      // TODO: Implement password validation (e.g., using bcrypt)

      // For now, we'll do a simple password check
      if (user.password !== password) {
        throw new Error('Invalid password.');
      }

      // Generate and return a token for the logged-in user
      const token = generateToken(user);

      // Return the user data without the password
      return {
        id: user.id,
        ...user._doc,
        password: null,
        token,
      };
    },
  },
};
```

Type Definitions:

```
module.exports = gql`
type Recipe {
  name: String
  description: String
  createdAt: String
  thumbsUp: Int
  thumbsDown: Int
  createdBy: ID! 
}


  type User {
    id: ID!
    username: String!
    email: String!
    createdAt: String!
    updatedAt: String!
    token: String!
  }

  input RecipeInput {
    name: String
    description: String
  }

  input RegisterInput {
    username: String!
    email: String!
    password: String!
    confirmPassword: String!
  }

  input LoginInput {
    username: String!
    password: String!
  }

  type Query {
    recipe(ID: ID!): Recipe!
    getRecipes(amount: Int): [Recipe]
    getUserRecipes: [Recipe]!
  }

  type Mutation {
    createRecipe(recipeInput: RecipeInput): Recipe!
    deleteRecipe(ID: ID!): Boolean
    editRecipe(ID: ID!, recipeInput: RecipeInput): Boolean
    register(registerInput: RegisterInput): User!
    login(loginInput: LoginInput): User!
  }
`;
```

When creating a recipe, the createdBy field in the recipe model should be populated with the user ID.
When calling the getUserRecipes query, it should return all the recipes related to the logged-in user.

Any help in identifying the issue and resolving it would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Could you expand on "but it's not working as expected?" What are you getting vs. what you expect?